# Python and mySQL rowcount not behaving as expected

Tags: python, mysql

I am teaching myself python and have a function called mysqltimedcheck()

This executes a very basic mySQL SELECT statement and returns the rowcount.

If i cange the value of 'shown' from 0 to 1 in the mysql table (while the script is running) for example the rowcount does not change.

I can see when debugging that it reruns the cursor.execute line again but still prints an old value

here is my function:

```
def mysqltimedcheck():
    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True) 
    window.after(1500, mysqltimedcheck)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE shown =  0") 
    rc = cursor.rowcount
    print(rc)
```

If i restart my test application then it pulls the correct rowcount value but changing this value while running does not show as correct.

I feel im missing something very basic.

Thanks for your help

Comment: does the execution return the correct value for shown=0? Also, could you maybe try adding mydb.commit() just in case.

Comment: @LabibaKanij
yes it does, i have two rows with shown = 0 when i run the function the output is 2 , when i change one of the rows to 1 the rowcount is still 2. If i restart the script it then correctly pulls 1.... THANKYOU the mydb.commit worked!

Submit it as an answer and i will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @LabibaKanij

adding mydb.commit() worked correctly and allowed me to change the value in the table and it changed for my script without restarting.